# Run php script monthly on windows based server

Tags: php, autorun

I need your help to run following php script automatically on 05th day of the every month. Currently I run this manually. Is this possible using schedule task? 
Also I don't have admin access to the web server. Therefore cannot use third party automation tools.

**PS:**
Is it possible to schedule this in a local machine with windows 7 xampp environment and then later update remote db?

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['log'] != "log" || $_SESSION['type'] != "***"){
    header("Location: ***.php");
}

require_once('conf.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date("j"); //get current date
$today = date("d-m-Y");  
$now = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm

if ($date === 5){
    //get interest rate
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Rate FROM Interest WHERE Ref = 'Loan' ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1");
    $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $rate = $r['Rate'];

    //check for not settled loans
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT LID FROM Registry WHERE Status = 0");
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
        while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {     // while there are rows to be fetched...
        //*** Start Transaction ***//  
            mysql_query("BEGIN");  

            $loanID = $list['LID'];

            //get loan data
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Registry.Amount, SUM(Account.Total) AS Paid, SUM(Account.Interest) AS intPaid FROM Registry LEFT JOIN Account ON Registry.LID = Account.LID WHERE Registry.Status = 0 AND Account.Auto = 0 AND (Account.LID = '$loanID') GROUP BY Account.LID");
            $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $amount = $r['Amount']; //loan amount
            $paid = $r['Paid'];     //sum of paid
            $intPaid = $r['intPaid'];   //sum of interest paid

            //get sum of monthly automatically updated interest
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Interest) AS Interest FROM Account WHERE Payment = 0 AND Auto = 1 AND LID = '$loanID'");
            $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $autoInt = $r['Interest'];  

            $total = ($amount + $autoInt);  //total to be paid
            $balance = ($total - $paid);    //with no interest

            if ($paid >= $balance){
//              echo "Loan completed <br/>";
            }else{
                $int = ($balance * $rate) / 100;
                $update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Account (LID, Date, Interest, Total, Auto) VALUES ('$loanID', NOW(), '$int', '$int', 1)") or die(mysql_error());

                if (! $update){
                //*** RollBack Transaction ***//  
                mysql_query("ROLLBACK");  
//                  $_SESSION['error'] = "Interest saving failed.!";
                    echo "Loan ID: " . $loanID . ", Interest: Rs. " . $int . "/= - Update Failed.!<br>";
                }else{
                //*** Commit Transaction ***//  
                    mysql_query("COMMIT");  
//                  $_SESSION['error'] = "Interest saved successfully";
                    echo "Loan ID: " . $loanID . ", Interest: Rs. " . $int . "/= - Update Succeeded.!<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Monthly Interest can be update only by 05th day of the month.!";
}
```

Comment: you could get a host that has cron ability (or use your own machine) and just fetch that page when required ie `wget http://otherserver.com/myscript.php` to get that page in linux

Comment: @mlwacosmos OP does not have admin access, so I assume could not run a shell command

Comment: you can run a shell as anyone

Comment: @nirosha - do you have access to the desktop via RDC? You don't need administrator access to use the Scheduler system, as far as I know - it'll just run as your user rather than as admin.

Comment: @halfer - No. I only have access to the mysql database and to the web site folder.

Comment: @nirosha: if you don't have desktop or shell access, then your hosting is insufficient for your (most!) needs, and I would recommend changing. If you don't specifically need Windows, I'd recommend switching to Linux anyway, so you don't need to pay for the license.

Comment: You can call a script on any remote machine that "visits" you webpage, you can use wget (there are ports for Windows) or PHP's file_get_contents() function.

Comment: @halfer-I have hosted this site in my campus web server and the site for the campus welfare organisation (non-profit). Therefore cannot move to outside.

Comment: @DanielP-Any examples please.

Comment: as its pretty much all database work, Have you looked in to mysql events ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: @user1281385-Thanks for your opinion. I'll try on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think `at` needs admin permissions

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true

EDIT:

or even try MySQL Events

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

It looks all database work which should be easily do able

Comment: But it has to create a batch file and run the same with schedule task in the remote web server.

Comment: Use the PHP script and call exec to organise the next task.

Comment: Thanks for the Events opinion. I'll try on it.

Comment: It is going to be a very tricky event schedule for the script. Trying.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a publicly accesseable web server, you can use a cronjob service like https://www.cronjobservice.net/. After registration you enter an url and the time they shall call it.  I advice using multiple of those services for the case one fails. (your script must execute on first call and exit on subsequent calls from other services.)

Please be sure to properly deal with .htaccess and make sure to have no security relevant output.

Comment: Is it safe to use 3rd party services? Since this web site used for loan and account handling system.

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka Depends on your script. The service will do a url call, just like any user could. If your system can be compromized by just calling a url, cronjobs are the least of your problems. Just make sure you have error repoting off and echo nothing but a "done" or alike.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt. I'll check on it.

Comment: Using an external free service could be considered a business risk though - trivial scheduling should be done locally.

Comment: @halfer: Account handling should not be done on a windows mashine, in php, without admin access. I believe this web service will be the most trustworthy part. :)

Comment: @Zsolt: not sure I understand. For security reasons, PHP scripts should not run as administrator unless it is absolutely necessary - this database script only needs ordinary account permissions.

Comment: @halfer I rather ment that they do not have admin access at all (hence the trouble creating conjobs)

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka Please don´t forget to upvote and accept answers that helped you, to help people with similar problems visiting that site.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy-Sure. I was busy reading the MySQL Events. BTW the first thing I saw after posting the quiz is someone down vote the quiz without any comment or reason. It is discouraging someone who has less knowledge on the it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you asked the peoples that are hosting your site if they have a solution?
Most hosting companies have solutions for this (even on Windows servers)

If the hosting company has no solution for this (what I seriously doubt) you can call the script externally from another server that has cron possibilities or have it called by the first visitor on that day.

I any case you will want to include a check in your script that your script only runs on the set date (you already have that) and also make sure that calling the script more than once on that day is no problem.

PS : if the script is called by the first visitor you will have to consider the fact that you could not have any visitor that particular day, so the script will have to run whenever the next visitor comes along.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Script is only can be run by the admin and he has to log in and hit the link in each and every 5th day of the month. It is the drawback of the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have administrative access to Windows, you won't be able to create a scheduled task. Your only alternative is to create some sort of custom task component in your application that checks / stores the last time a script was run. The problem with this is that it relies on user activity and it may not run on the exact date that you want it to.

The other alternative is to find Linux hosting so that you can avail of Cron.

Comment: Is it safe to use third party service in the web server? Or how can I run as a scheduled task (then I can run it in the local xampp server and can update the remote database.) in windows 7 xampp environment?